# Discrete dense subset

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $K$ be a compact Hausdorff space such that the set $D$ of isolated points in $K$ is countable and dense in $K$. Consider the linear subspace $A$ of $C(K)$ consisting of those functions $f\in C(K)$ such that $f$ is constant on $K\setminus D$ and the set $\{x\in D\colon f(x)= 0\}$ is finite or its complement in D is finite.

Is $A$ a closed subspace of $C(K)$?

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: first, do you have an example of compact space whith dense isolated points that has non-isolated points ?

Comment: What is the topology of $C(K)$?

Comment: $C(K)$ is regarded as a Banach space with the supremum norm.

Comment: So what a neighborhood of a function $f \in C(K)$ would be like?

Comment: Typically, a ball $\{g\in C(K): \sup_{x\in K}|f(x)-g(x)|<\varepsilon\}$.

Answer (score 4):

1. Try a very simple space for an example.  Can you find one which has only one non-isolated point?
2. On this space, find a continuous function $f \notin A$.
3. Find a sequence of functions $f_n \in A$ such that $f_n \to f$ uniformly.  This will show that $A$ is not closed.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot give a full solution to your problem, but
here is what I think I found out.

1. Let $y_1, \dots, y_n \in \mathbb{R}$ be any real numbers
   then for any $x_1,\dots,x_n \in D$ define
   $f(x_i) = y_i$ and $f(x) = 0$ everywhere else.
   For every closed $A \subset R$ you have $f^{-1}(A)$
   closed in $K$ hence $f$ is continuous and so $f \in A$.
2. Any $g \in C(K)$ which is not constant on $K\setminus{D}$ 
   lies in the interior of $C(K)\setminus{A}$, as all the $h \in C(K)$
   with $\|g-h\|< \frac{1}{2} (\max_{x \in K\setminus{D}}{g(x)} - \min_{x \in K\setminus{D}}{g(x)})$
   cannot be constant on $K\setminus{D}$.
3. This leaves us considering $g \in C(K)$ with $g(x) = y_0$ 
   for all $x \in K\setminus{D}$ and some $y_0$ and $g(x) = 0$ 
   for infinitely many $x \in D$ and $g(x) \neq 0$ for infinitely many $x \in D$. 
   Note that for any open neighborhood $U$ of $y_0$ we have 
   $g^{-1}(U)$ containig all but finitely many elements of $D$. 
   Hence we conclude $y_0 = 0$.
   Now for every $\varepsilon > 0$ you can choose $f \in A$
   with $f(x) = g(x)$ for all $x \in D$ with $|g(x)| \geq \varepsilon$
   and $f(x) = 0$ everywhere else.
   It follows that $\|f-g\| < \varepsilon$ and as $\varepsilon >0$ was
   arbitrary we conclude $g \in \overline{A}$.
4. So all in all $A$ is not closed as long as the second condition is
   not superfluous.